# unix file test operator with using grep for other test

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I would like to check two conditions. I have a file that is created that could have an error string "ORA-" inside it. I want to check first if the file exists and/or was created, then second if the file that exists has that specific error string. If it does, do not proceed with next step. If it doesn't have it, then proceed. I use `grep` to check the string, however I'm not sure if i'm using the correct file test. What is a good way of checking for this?

```
TESTFILE=/tmp/usethisfile.sql
CHK_ERR= `grep "ORA-" $TESTFILE`;

if [ -e "$TESTFILE" ] && [ -z "$CHK_ERR" ]; 
then
    #run next step
else
    echo "Error found"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: If you don't need to distinguish between the file not existing and it existing but not matching "ORA-", you can skip the `-e` test and just let `grep` fail when it can't open the file.

Comment: you mean, just do if $CHK_ERR then exit, else next step?

Comment: Yes, just like anubhava's answer, but with `[ -e "$TESTFILE" ] &&` removed.

Comment: @chepner, thank you. This works as well. I could use either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
TESTFILE=/tmp/usethisfile.sql

if [ -e "$TESTFILE" ] && grep -q "ORA-" "$TESTFILE"
then
    #run next step
else
    echo "Error found"
    exit 1
fi
```